# How to edit app.config at runtime for different role and membership providers

Tags: app-config

I am working on a vb.net development project in Visual Studio 2015 and need to be able to edit the app.config for the project at run time in order to access role and membership providers for different web sites. I would like to be able to change the **ApplicationServices** settings in the **connectionStrings** section and the **applicationName** settings in the **membership and roleManager provider** sections. I have edited the initial **app.config** file in the project's base directory to look like this:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <configuration>
      <startup>
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5" />
      </startup>
      <connectionStrings>
        <clear />
        <add name="ApplicationServices" connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS; Integrated Security=True; User Instance=False; Connect Timeout=30; Initial Catalog=MYWEBSITE" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
      </connectionStrings>
      <system.web>
        <membership>
          <providers>
            <clear />
            <add name="AspNetSqlMembershipProvider" type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider" connectionStringName="ApplicationServices" applicationName="/" passwordFormat="Encrypted" enablePasswordRetrieval="true" enablePasswordReset="true" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="true" requiresUniqueEmail="true" maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="5" minRequiredPasswordLength="8" minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="1" passwordAttemptWindow="5" />
          </providers>
        </membership>
        <roleManager enabled="true">
          <providers>
            <clear />
            <add name="AspNetSqlRoleProvider" type="System.Web.Security.SqlRoleProvider" connectionStringName="ApplicationServices" applicationName="/" />
            <add name="AspNetWindowsTokenRoleProvider" type="System.Web.Security.WindowsTokenRoleProvider" applicationName="/" />
          </providers>
        </roleManager>
      </system.web>
    </configuration>
```

At run time I am attempting to fetch the settings from the projects **app.config** file shown above using the following code:

```
            Public Shared Function ReadAllConfigSettings(ByRef Configs(,) As String) As Boolean
        ReadAllConfigSettings = False
        Configs.Initialize()
        Dim ConfigCounter As Integer = 0
        Dim config As System.Configuration.Configuration = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(ConfigurationUserLevel.None)
        Try
            Dim Settings = config.AppSettings.Settings
            If Settings.Count = 0 Then
                ReadAllConfigSettings = False
                Exit Function
            Else
                For Each key As String In Settings.AllKeys
                    ConfigCounter = ConfigCounter + 1
                    Configs(ConfigCounter, 1) = key
                    Configs(ConfigCounter, 2) = Settings(key).Value
                Next
                ReadAllConfigSettings = True
            End If
        Catch e As ConfigurationErrorsException
            ReadAllConfigSettings = False
        End Try
    End Function
```

When I run the code above the **Settings** collection retrieved from the **Settings = config.AppSettings.Settings** line of code is always empty with null entries and the **Settings.Count** is 0.

I am stumped as to why this is not getting the setting I have added to the **app.config** file, and I cannot continue to work on changing them if I can't even figure out how to retrieve them. Can someone point me in the right direction?

Thanks!

David

Answer (score 0):

After re-thinking the process I came up with a solution that appears to be a way to do it without trying to edit the **app.config** file. Below is the code I scrambled together from fragment I found during my research into the problem:

```
            Public Shared Function UpdateMembership(ConnectionStr As String, AppName As String, UserName As String, OldPassword As String, NewPassword As String, TheQuestion As String, TheAnswer As String, Optional TheError As String = Nothing) As Boolean
        UpdateMembership = False
        Dim IsMember As Boolean = False
        Dim AUser As MembershipUser
        Dim ChangePassOK As Boolean = False
        Dim ChangeQAOK As Boolean = False
        Try
            Dim settings As Object = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("ApplicationServices")
            Dim fi As Object = GetType(ConfigurationElement).GetField("_bReadOnly", (BindingFlags.Instance Or BindingFlags.NonPublic))
            fi.SetValue(settings, False)
            settings.ConnectionString = ConnectionStr
            Membership.Providers.Item("AspNetSqlMembershipProvider").ApplicationName = AppName
            Roles.Providers.Item("AspNetSqlRoleProvider").ApplicationName = AppName
            Roles.Providers.Item("AspNetWindowsTokenRoleProvider").ApplicationName = AppName
            IsMember = Membership.ValidateUser(UserName, OldPassword)
            If IsMember Then
                AUser = Membership.GetUser(UserName, False)
                If Not IsNothing(AUser) Then
                    ChangePassOK = AUser.ChangePassword(OldPassword, NewPassword)
                    If ChangePassOK Then
                        ChangeQAOK = AUser.ChangePasswordQuestionAndAnswer(NewPassword, TheQuestion, TheAnswer)
                    End If
                    If ChangeQAOK Then
                        UpdateMembership = True
                    End If
                End If
            End If
        Catch ex As Exception
            If Not IsNothing(TheError) Then
                TheError = ex.Message
            End If
        End Try
    End Function
```

It works fine so it can be used to adjust the security settings for any user specific to each site's config.